# pass key value pair to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've seen a couple possible solutions but they look very messy to me. Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

**Model:**

```
 public class MyClass
    {       
        public KeyValuePair<int,string> Field { get; set; }
    }
```

**Get method in controller:**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyClass();
        model.Field = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "test");

        return View(model);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MyClass

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{       
   @Html.Hidden("Field", Model.Field);

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Post method in controller:**

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyClass input)
        {
            var x = input.Field;
            ....
        }
```

The Key Value pair is not passed  with this method as it just comes up empty. What would be the easiest way of getting 'Field' passed to the controller?

Comment: What is the value of the hidden field?  Is `Model.Field` null, or the kvp?

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line and try it.let me know any problem.

```
@Html.Hidden("Field", Model.Field);
```

TO

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field);
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves correctly, it has a Key and Value property, which like any other object would be bound like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field.Key)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field.Value)
```

One input field can't represent the key and value in this way, unless you look at using a [Custom Model Binder](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) to manage the value posted back, and a [Display/Editor template](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) to render the input in a way the model binder will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Following Brians answer, I've had to accept I must do it like this:

Class:

```
public class MyClass
    {

        public KeyValuePair<int,string> Field { get; set; }
        public string FieldKey { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.Hidden("FieldKey",Model.Field.Key)
@Html.Hidden("FieldValue", Model.Field.Value)
```

It will get messy as I have many of these kvp's I'd like to pass back to the controller, but I guess it's the only uncomplicated way.  It's not the first time I've wished it was possible to pass objects to a controller, and I'm sure it won't be the last.  Maybe we'll get the happy news in a dotnet update one day that we can do things like this more easily.